# vim: key-binding customization -- how far is too far?

Tags: vim, key-bindings

What are the pros and cons of changing vim's default keybindings? How far is too far? As a new learner of vim, I already have a glimpse of its power, but I am also much bothered by some key-bindings that don't make sense to me. Already, I have mapped `<c-l>` and `<c-h>` to `w` and `b` respectively. Now I'm itching to find a new key for `$` so that I won't have to press <kbd>shift</kbd> just to go to the end of line. To my mind, the basic motion keys should be one-button operations (my mapping above notwithstanding, I still use `w` and `b` in conjunction with `d` and `c` etc), and spatial logic should trump symbolic logic in deciding their placements. `-` is currently my candidate for replacing `$` because as a shift-free key to the right of `0` (for the beginning of line).

Should I go ahead, and thus opening the floodgate for potentially myriads of other changes? Or should I try to adapt to the default? One thing that's holding me back is my concern about unintended consequences that I, as a newbie, cannot foresee, including loss of functionality (such as what the `-` currently does, which doesn't seem like much to me). In addition, I'm not sure how I feel about customizing vim so much that I can work only with my vim and no others. Are these concerns valid or overblown? Thanks.

Comment: I'd say just go for it. Unless for whatever reason you'll end up using vi/vim on other computers often, customize however you want. As far as I can tell, there isn't much that's fundamentally great or set in stone about a lot of the default keybindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I say, go for it. Although it appears that you have already learned the vim model essentials somewhat well, there's no reason not to adjust it to *your* personal needs and preferences. One shouldn't aim to target the lower common denominator, even if "plain vi" is pretty high as such. Although I don't exactly know what's the case with `C-l` and `C-h` if you also use `w` and `b` comfortably, there's always a case for meaningful helpers.

If you are worried about ssh'ing to foreign machines without your vim configs, worry no more. Vim has a satisfactory remote editing capabilities; edit over SSH/SCP locally.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement. I explained why `w` and `b` are awkward to me in a comment to priomsrb. By the way, either a word is missing in your answer ("there's no reason **not** to adjust it...") or I've misunderstood you completely.

Comment: @bongbang, damn me. :) The pretty essential 'not' was missing alright.

Answer (score 3):

While I agree that some vim key-bindings can be awkward, you should start off following the defaults in the beginning. After some time most of it becomes muscle memory and it shouldn't bother you much. If after a long time you still feel uncomfortable, feel free to rebind some keys. For example I have `<CTRL-S>` bound to save because it's easier than pressing `<ESC>:w<CR>` and less confusing when I'm working with other editors.

If you start rebinding too many keys too early, you will find it frustrating to use vanilla vim (for example on a remote machine).

As for your examples, I personally think `<c-l>` and `<c-h>` are harder to press than `w` and `b`. For example `cw` is a common vim operation and can be done using one hand compared to `c<c-l>`.

Comment: `w` and `b` are awkward to me when the purpose is to move the cursor to the desired place. The keys are far apart, neither is on the home row, and -- worst of all -- `w` is on the the left and `b` on the right. It's the opposite of both reality and the spatial logic of `h` and `l`. The keys don't feel so bad when applied after `d` or `w`, because the idea of movement is less explicit, which is why I continue to use them.